# Angular JS routing returns "HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden" on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

I am using the angular JS for routing between the pages... Everything is working fine when we redirect from one page to another. 
But I am getting "HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden" error when the page is refreshed or reloaded. Below is my script. Please let us know what we are doing wrong here.

```
function (ng) {
       "use strict";
       return ng.module("app", ["angularSpinner", "app.controllers", "ui.router"]).config(["$compileProvider", "$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider", "$locationProvider",
           function ($compileProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
               $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|javascript):/), $locationProvider.html5Mode({
                   enabled: !0, requireBase: !1
               }), $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/"),
               $stateProvider
                   .state("home", { url: "/", templateUrl: "../views/page1.html" })
                   .state("form", { url: "/contact", templateUrl: "../views/page2.html" })
                   .state("finalpage", { url: "/final", templateUrl: "../views/page3.html"})
           }])
           .run(["$rootScope", "$state", "$stateParams", "$location", "$http", "$templateCache", "$timeout",
               function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams, $location, $http, $templateCache, $timeout) {
                   $rootScope.$state = $state,
                   $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams,
                   $("#init-loading").hide(), $rootScope.$watch(function ()
                   {
               return $location.path()
           }, function (a) {
               $rootScope.showSpinner = !0, $timeout(function () {
                   $rootScope.showSpinner = !1
               }, 300)
           })
       }])
   }
```

Comment: Your server returning 403 has nothing to do with angular, its to do with authorization on the server.

Comment: Which Technology you are using for server side?